# Deduce parent class of inherited method in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Take the following class hierarchy:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    T fooMethod() { ... }
};
class Moo : public Foo<bool> {
    ...
};
```

If I now somewhere write `Moo::fooMethod` the compiler will deduce `Foo<bool>::fooMethod`. How can I deduce `Foo<bool>` as parent of `fooMethod` myself before compile time?

Motivation: the compiler will not allow `Foo<bool>::fooMethod` to be passed as template parameter for `bool (Moo::*)()` since it will be of type `bool (Foo<bool>::*)()` in that context. But since I have multiple inheritance I dont know what parent `fooMethod` will be in, it must be deduced.

Comment: I don't suppose just [using an rvalue-reference](http://ideone.com/AZsFOx) is a possibility?

Comment: Is a simple pass through function going to be acceptable/not too inconvenient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, it is possible to deduce the class a member function is defined in, using the following trait:

```
template<typename>
struct member_class_t;

template<typename R, typename C, typename... A>
struct member_class_t <R(C::*)(A...)> { using type = C; };

template<typename R, typename C, typename... A>
struct member_class_t <R(C::*)(A...) const> { using type = C const; };

// ...other qualifier specializations

template<typename M>
using member_class = typename member_class_t <M>::type;
```

after which you can write

```
member_class<decltype(&Moo::fooMethod)>
```

giving `Foo<bool>`.

To define `member_class` more generally, you should take into account `volatile` and `ref`-qualifiers as well, yielding a total of about 12 specializations. A complete definition is [here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/type/traits/member.hpp).

Comment: This simple decomposition is exactly what I was looking for, brilliant! :) Thanks a lot!